# Push JHipster 6.0.1 to Gitlab repository

Tags: docker, gitlab, jhipster, jib

After having everything ready to deploy, I realized `JHipster` doesn't have a *Dockerfile* anymore and the packaging is done with `jib`. The generated `gitlab-ci.yml` has a docker-push stage with a command like this:

```
./mvnw jib:build -Djib.to.image=$IMAGE_TAG -Djib.to.auth.username=gitlab-ci-token  -Djib.to.auth.password=$CI_BUILD_TOKEN
```

but it fails with

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.google.cloud.tools:jib-maven-plugin:0.9.11:build (default-cli) on project test-project: Obtaining project build output files failed; make sure you have compiled your project before trying to build the image. (Did you accidentally run "mvn clean jib:build" instead of "mvn clean compile jib:build"?): /builds/amatos/test-project/target/classes -> [Help 1]
```

As that failed, I tried to run the command locally like this:

```
./mvnw jib:build -Djib.to.image=registry.gitlab.com/amatos/test-project:v6.0.1 -Djib.to.auth.username=amatos -Djib.to.auth.password=password
```

but instead of trying to connect to Gitlab's registry, it tries to connect to [registry.hub.docker.com](http://registry.hub.docker.com):

```
[INFO] Retrieving registry credentials for registry.hub.docker.com...
```

What I would like to know is: how do I set it to connect to Gitlab instead of Docker Hub?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to connect to a custom repository, I changed `-Djib.to.image` to `-Dimage` and it worked

Answer (score 2):

This is followed by [jhipster/generator-jhipster issue 9761](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/9761) which states:

> as the `docker-push` is done in another stage, there is a missing - `target/classes` in the previous stage.
>   It is needed by `jib`. It should look like:

```
maven-package:
  stage: package
  script:
    - ./mvnw verify -Pprod -DskipTests -Dmaven.repo.local=$MAVEN_USER_HOME
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - target/*.jar
      - target/classes
    expire_in: 1 day
```

Possibly addressed by [PR (merged) 9762](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/9762), [commit 50cc009](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/commit/50cc0098545d895a5536ccc07f2e0732dac0fb4b), which is only in master, not yet referenced by any tag.

Comment: actually the issue was solved by changing `-Djib.to.image` to `-Dimage` and then it connected to gitlab's registry

Comment: thanks! what I don't understand is how this can work in gitlab's pipeline if this does not work on a local machine. And btw: the image doesn't run using `docker-compose`, it complains about memory heap although I'm setting 3gb